# Trouble differentiating $\int_1^{x^3}\arcsin(t)dt$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with an integral problem which goes like this: Differentiate $$\int_1^{x^3}\arcsin(t)dt$$

The rule I know would be that you make $t$ equal to $x^3$ and then use the chain rule to achieve:
$$ 3x^2\arcsin(x^3)$$

But the answer says that it is actually:
$$ 3x^2\arcsin(3x^3)$$

Why is this?

Comment: You are totally correct ! One more typo in a textbook.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Claude, this makes me a happy man :)

Comment: **You** are brilliant ! I did not do anything. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct. It is a general fact that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_c^{g(x)} f(t) dt=g'(x) f(g(x))$$

due to both the FTC and chain rule. Your book likely had a typo.